# In IE 8, what the quickest way to save a web page (and all of it's contents) offline for viewing?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I want to save a webpage and everything in it for offline viewing. Each page also has tabs within it...can that be saved too or only what you see on the screen can be saved? I want to save all pages at a specific URL. Can that be done and will the contents within the page be functional offline?

I'm open to software that does a good job too. Paid or free.

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

In IE quickest way to save a single Page, zoom it back all the way until you see the entire page you can use CTRL **- +** to zoom.  Then go to SaveAs (in Page or File menu) in the "Save As Type" Select Web Archive, and give it a file name or not. then zoom back in.
To view offline, just click on the archive, it will open in the normal browser.

Thats it, MS Removed Offlining favorites and deep links.

Offlining deeper links takes some time to get used to the program, and set things so your not overdoing it or underdoing it, a person is going to want to filter and control, and each site you want to offline can be way different.
There are many 3rd party "offline browsers" that will do the best they can to offline some pages and links to, they vary based on if your trying to leech or offline. http://www.httrack.com/html/index.html